# IDE recomendation for postscript

Tags: software-recommendation, postscript

Im learning postscript to use in making vector art with my laser-cutter. 
I have been straight typing all the code, and began wondering what is out there for PostScript IDE.

Comment: I would have asked this on https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ It is a siter site dedicated to these kind of questions ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try [PostScript Development Tools for Eclipse](http://thomas-fritsch.github.io/psdt/).

It features syntax coloring, outline view, code folding, content assist, auto-edit for brackets, marked syntax errors, debugger, documentation, integration with `ghostscript`.